# Avoid for loop in Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

Problem 1.

Suppose I have n years of annual returns `r` and my initial wealth is `100`. Every year I have fixed expense of 6. I want to create yearly wealth. I can do it in for loop. But for my purpose it's time consuming. How do I do it in DataFrame?

```
wealth = pd.Series(index = range(n+1))
wealth[0] = 100
for i in range(n):
    wealth.iloc[i+1] = wealth.iloc[i]*(1+r.iloc[i]) - 6
```

Initially I thought

```
wealth = ((1 + r - 0.06).cumprod()).multiply(other = 100)
```

to be the solution. But it is not. Expenses are not 6%. They are fixed. It is 6.

Problem 2.

I want to do the above N times. In each case I generate `r` by sampling n returns with replacement.

```
r = returnY.sample(n,replace=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then for that return, create the wealth path I described above and create a n*N dateframe of wealth paths. I can do this in for loop, but for big `N` and `n`, it takes long time to run. Is there an efficient and elegant way to do this?

Problem 3.

Suppose `allWealth` is the DF with all wealth paths. Want to check %columns in each row less than 0. This is how I resolved it.

```
yy = allWealth.copy()
yy[yy>0] = 1
yy[yy<=0] = 0
yy.sum(axis = 1)/N
```

Any better, more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1: It looks like you want to apply the "reduce" pattern. You can use `reduce` function from `functools`.

```py
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce
rs = np.random.random(50)*0.3   #sequence of annual returns
result = reduce(lambda w,r: w*(1+r)-6, rs, 100)
```

If you want to keep all the intermediate values, use `itertools.accumulate()` instead. For example, replace the last line with the following:

```py
ts_iter= itertools.accumulate(rs, lambda w,r: w*(1+r)-6, initial=100)
ts = list(ts_iter)     #itertools.accumulate returns an iterable
```

Problem 2: You can first generate a random matrix of nxN by sampling with replacement. Then you can use "apply_along_axis" method for each column.

```py
import numpy as np
rm = np.random.random((n,N))
def sim(rs):
    return reduce(lambda w,r: w * (1+r) - 6, rs, 100)
result = np.apply_along_axis(sim, 0, rm)
```

Problem 3: you don't need to assign ones and zeros to your original dataframe. A mask dataframe of `True` and `False` implicitly acts as a dataframe of ones and zeros in this case.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((50,30)))
mask = df < 0.5
mask.sum(axis=1)/30
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. sim, defined above, gave me the end wealth. I need to track all time-series. So in your first example, you generated 50 returns. I need all 50 resulting wealth.

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-429c23746661> in <module>
----> 1 ts_iter= accumulate(rm, lambda w,r: w*(1+r)-6, initial=100)
      2 # list(ts_iter)
      3 
      4 print(ts_iter)

TypeError: accumulate() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Answer (score 0):

I used @chi's solution with some small edit.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

rm = np.random.random((n,N))   #sequence of annual returns
rm0 = np.insert(rm, 0, 100, axis=1)

def wealth(rs):
    return list(itertools.accumulate(rs, lambda w,r: w*(1+r)-6))

result = np.apply_along_axis(wealth, 1, rm0)
```

itertools.accumulate does not recognize initial. Hence inserted initial wealth at the front of return array.